# Secured annotaion

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've got a servlet that handles POST and GET requests. GET requests are available for everyone, but POST requests are for `ROLE_ADMIN` only. If I annotate my method with `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`, regular user will catch

> 405 Request method 'POST' not supported

How can I make my servlet throw 403 instead?

Comment: What about the checking the admin role inside the `POST` method.?

Comment: Seems to be pretty similar to the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375989/spring-returns-http-405-for-every-http-post-which-isnt-authorized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring security login-processing-url throws 405 request method POST not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964470/spring-security-login-processing-url-throws-405-request-method-post-not-supporte)